# Prevent write access to XML file from EXE duplicate

Tags: c#, xml, windows

So I have this WinForms EXE (VS2010) which reads and writes from / to a single XML file like this:

```
// read
FileStream dbXmlFileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
myDataSet.ReadXml(dbXmlFileStream);
dbXmlFileStream.Close();

// write
myDataSet.AcceptChanges();
StreamWriter xmlSW = new StreamWriter(path);
myDataSet.WriteXml(xmlSW, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
xmlSW.Close();
```

The XML file lives on a networked drive and is shared by multiple instances of the same EXE (also on the same networked path). So each user has a shortcut on their machine pointing to the same EXE.

Whoever accesses the EXE first ("first" as in the 1st EXE instance running) should get exclusive write access to the XML. Subsequent EXE instances should be able to read (i.e. throw no errors when opening the EXE) but get a locking error when trying to save into the same XML via their EXE instance.

With my code, there are no exceptions thrown while multiple users read or write into the file. However, it's misleading because in the case where all of them attempted to save something at the same time, only the most recent save persists on the disk.

How can I remove ambiguity and actually capture write lock exceptions for any subsequent users?

I tried different variations of FileAccess and FileShare enums in File.Open with no luck.

Comment: You're opening and closing the file twice.  In order to use file locking to maintain consistency, you need to leave the file open until you're done.

Comment: I was going to write the same (something similar) as @HarryJohnston, you might want to take a look at this example too which might be of some use http://mvolo.com/fun-with-file-locking/

Comment: Unbelievable! it was right in front of me. Thank you for opening my eyes guys.